error: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions, but the array at index 0 has 1 dimension(s) and the array at index 1 has 2 dimensions
Getting the below error while executing the code for the ravdess dataset
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/librosa/core/spectrum.py:266: UserWarning: n_fft=2048 is too large for input signal of length=2
  warnings.warn(
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-5cc83e014a5a> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = loadData(test_size=0.23)

2 frames
<ipython-input-25-09a146490aa3> in loadData(test_size)
      6     if emotion1 not in observedEmotions:
      7       continue
----> 8     feature = extractFeature(file, mfcc=True, chroma=True, mel=True)
      9     x.append(feature)
     10     y.append(emotion1)

<ipython-input-23-13df96df67ad> in extractFeature(fileName, mfcc, chroma, mel)
      8     if mfcc:
      9       mfccs=np.mean(librosa.feature.mfcc(y=X, sr=sampleRate, n_mfcc=40).T, axis=0)
---> 10       result=np.hstack((result,mfccs))
     11     if chroma:
     12       chroma=np.mean(librosa.feature.chroma_stft(S=stft, sr=sampleRate).T, axis=0)

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/numpy/core/shape_base.py in hstack(tup, dtype, casting)
    355     # As a special case, dimension 0 of 1-dimensional arrays is "horizontal"
    356     if arrs and arrs[0].ndim == 1:
--> 357         return _nx.concatenate(arrs, 0, dtype=dtype, casting=casting)
    358     else:
    359         return _nx.concatenate(arrs, 1, dtype=dtype, casting=casting)

ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions, but the array at index 0 has 1 dimension(s) and the array at index 1 has 2 dimension(s)


I'm expecting to run this and data need to get splitted
def extractFeature(fileName, mfcc,chroma, mel):
  with sf.SoundFile(fileName) as sound_file:
    X = sound_file.read(dtype='float32')
    sampleRate=sound_file.samplerate
    result=np.array([])
    if chroma:
      stft=np.abs(librosa.stft(X))
    if mfcc:
      mfccs=np.mean(librosa.feature.mfcc(y=X, sr=sampleRate, n_mfcc=40).T, axis=0)
      result=np.hstack((result,mfccs))
    if chroma:
      chroma=np.mean(librosa.feature.chroma_stft(S=stft, sr=sampleRate).T, axis=0)
      result=np.hstack((result,chroma))
    if mel:
      mel=np.mean(librosa.feature.melspectrogram(y=X, sr=sampleRate).T, axis=0)
      result=np.hstack((result,mel))
  return result

emotions={
    '01':'neutral',
    '02':'calm',
    '03':'happy',
    '04':'sad',
    '05':'angry',
    '06':'fearful',
    '07':'disgust',
    '08':'surprised'
}
observedEmotions=['calm','happy','fearful','disgust']


def loadData(test_size=0.2):
  x,y=[],[]
  for file in glob.glob("/content/drive/MyDrive/RAVDESS/Actor_*/*.wav"):
    fileName=os.path.basename(file)
    emotion1=emotions[fileName.split('-')[2]]
    if emotion1 not in observedEmotions:
      continue
    feature = extractFeature(file, mfcc=True, chroma=True, mel=True)
    x.append(feature)
    y.append(emotion1)
  return train_test_split(np.array(x),y,test_size=test_size, random_state=9)

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = loadData(test_size=0.23)


In result=np.hstack((result,mfccs)), what's the shape of result and mfccs? Why?

result=np.array([]) is 1d.  Then mfcs should be as well.  Without your data files we can't test or determine why it is actually 2d?  Is this your own code, that you tested?  or borrowed without real understanding?
